Pagination API Request in Python
I am trying to pull all pages from this specific endpoint in the API, and then convert the .json responses into a Pandas Dataframe. My mechanic is looking at a Key Value in the .json file, which is nested in the "meta" key, under hasMore`.  If there is another page of results, it will produce True, if no more pages, it will return False as the values.
I can print the result of has_More and it comes back True, so I know it has found the correct value. However, when I run the function, I get back a blank list with .json or dataframes.  Been at this for awhile trying new code, but always get back blank lists.
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/projects/api/v3/tasklists"

def get_all_tasklists(url, pageSize=100, page=1):

    response = requests.get(f'{url}?page={page}&pageSize={pageSize}',
                            headers = {"authorization": xxxxxxxxxxxx}
                            )
    
    meta_data = json.loads(response.text)['meta']
    has_More = meta_data['page']['hasMore']

    timelogs = []
  
    if has_More == True:
        x = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response.text))
        timelogs.extend(x)
        page += 1
    else:
        print(timelogs)
    


get_all_tasklists(url, pageSize=100, page=1)


x is being overwritten on every loop. Append the dataframes to a list and use concat.

I'm assuming you're correct cause you probably know more about coding than I do (not even 2 months experience), but I'm just curious as to why I don't want x to be over written?  My thinking is I do want to overwrite it every time with the new .json response that is being "cleaned" with json_normalize?

If you overwrite the variable, the data it was referencing is "lost". So each loop would effectively discard the data fetched in the previous loop. Unless you store a reference to it somewhere else, like in a list for example.

A couple problems:
One, your code will only ever fetch one page per call. Given that you've named it get_all_xxx, this is probably not intended behavior. Two, you're using list.extend instead of list.append, which is probably what you want. Three, there's no return on this function.
I've tweaked and cleaned up your code, this should serve as a minimal working example of what you'll need. It's still missing error handling around the request itself, but this should be a good base. Note that the pagination is now within a loop.
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/projects/api/v3/tasklists"

def get_all_tasklists(url, pageSize=100, page=1):
    dataframes = []

    while True:
        response = requests.get(
            f'{url}?page={page}&pageSize={pageSize}',
            headers = {"authorization": xxxxxxxxxxxx}
        )

        meta_data = json.loads(response.text)['meta']
        has_more = meta_data['page']['hasMore']

        x = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response.text))
        dataframes.append(x)
  
        if has_more:
            page += 1
        else:
            return pd.concat(timelogs)
    
get_all_tasklists(url, pageSize=100, page=1)


Damn you're good.  Exactly what I wanted.  This shit was way harder than expected (especially as a noob).  So "While True: is checking "if has_More:" being True? If it is, keep initiating response -> look at my meta_Data/has_More for bool value -> load json into to normalize and add to my DF list -> If bool value is now False, take all the time logs in the list and put them into one?

More or less. This loop is effectively: Fetch -> append to list -> if more, GOTO 1, if no more, break, glue together list.
This code has a couple sharp corners in it that you may wish to try to solve as an exercise - what happens if the first page is empty (ie zero API results)? What happens if you get several pages in, and suddenly an invalid JSON result comes through - are you going to try to keep what's left, or fail the whole function execution?

@MichaelMesa while True: is basically just an infinite loop. You get out of it with the "return".
